# Destroying Angular Components based on Need

Tags: angular, service, components

So I am facing difficulty in destroying the instance of service. Here is the scenario. My webpage is divided into two section. The left half is grid with request items per row and edit button as one of the column and the right half is a form, which will be filled based on edit click of any one of the row in the grid.

In my Form component, I am using a service (component level). So the challenge here is, if I click on row 1 edit, everything works fine. My new service instance will be created. However, if I click on row 2 edit, new instance of the service is not getting created as the component is not getting destroyed.

How can I make sure that I will get a new component instance here??

Answer (score 0):

You can use destroy() from angular core. More details . [Destroy](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef)